# Bootstrap modal pop up breaks when i send "schemaname.tablename" into id field using Django Jinjna template

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

Below is my html script when I am sending a schema_name.table_name to the 'id' attribute of my modal and pop up modal is not displayed and the popup modal breaks, but work well as mentioned in the below note

**note: when I only send table_name to 'id' attribute, pop up is displayed but I need to send schema_name as well please help**

```
    <input type="checkbox" id='dbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history' name="acs[]" value="dbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history"> dbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history

    <!--                <form action="/dwdatacatlog2/" method="GET">-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaldbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history">Add
        filter

        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus-circle" fill="currentColor"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
        </svg>
    </button>

    <!--         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>-->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModaldbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Add Filters</h4>
                    <!--                      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>-->
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><small>Table name</small></p>
                    <p>dbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history</p>
                    <p>
                        <select id="columnname" name="columnname" class="form-control"
                                onchange="changecat(this);">
                            <!-- onchange="populatefilter()"-->

                            
                            <option value="int////audit_id"> audit_id<small>(int)</small></option>


                            
                            <option value="int////segment_id"> segment_id<small>(int)</small></option>


                            
                            <option value="varchar////segment_name"> segment_name<small>(varchar)</small></option>


                            
                            <option value="varchar////customer_hash"> customer_hash<small>(varchar)</small></option>


                            
                            <option value="varchar////created_by"> created_by<small>(varchar)</small></option>


                            
                            <option value="datetime////created_on"> created_on<small>(datetime)</small></option>


                            
                        </select>
                        <br>

                        </select>
                        <select name="datatype" id="datatype" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="parametervalue" class="form-control" aria-label="Default"
                               aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
                               placeholder="enter corresponding column value" required="True">

                                       </option>
                </div>
              


                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary  "> Submit</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--                </form>-->

</tr>
<!--         -->
<tr>
    <br>

    <!--        <input  type="button"  value="filter"> -->
    <hr>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attribute id='dbo.segment_customer_hash_mapping_history' the '.' is causing issue for modal popup

made backend changes so that id will not dot '.' and this work around help me